# petl - how to replace empty values with zeros

Tags: python, etl, petl

For a petl table, how do I replace empty values with zeros?

I would expect something like the following:

```
tb_probii = etl.fromcsv("data.csv").fill("score", "", 0)
```

Looked for a similar function here:
http://petl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/petl/transform/fills.html

But no luck :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed the help group python-etl@googlegroups.com and the creator himself responded with a function that worked perfectly:

```
tb_probii = etl.fromcsv("data.csv").replace("score", "", 0)
```

Comment: I intended to ask you if you'd found a better way. A very pleasant learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best way or not. I'm actually grateful to you for bringing the existence of `petl` to my attention.

```
>>> import petl
>>> tb_probii = petl.fromcsv('trial.csv')
>>> tb_probii
+------+-------+
| team | score |
+======+=======+
| 'A'  | ''    |
+------+-------+
| 'B'  | '25'  |
+------+-------+
| 'C'  | '35'  |
+------+-------+

>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> mappings = OrderedDict()
>>> def f(s):
...     if s == '':
...         return '0'
...     else:
...         return s
...     
>>> mappings['team'] = 'team'
>>> mappings['score'] = 'score', lambda s: f(s)
>>> tb_probii = petl.fieldmap(tb_probii, mappings)
>>> tb_probii 
+-------+------+
| score | team |
+=======+======+
| '0'   | 'A'  |
+-------+------+
| '25'  | 'B'  |
+-------+------+
| '35'  | 'C'  |
+-------+------+
```

Some explanation:
`fieldmap` executes the collection of mappings contained in an `OrderedDict`. When I tried this out I did the mapping to a new table. That's why `team` is mapped identically to itself. This may be unnecessary if you are keeping the same table, although I somehow doubt it. Each mapping is a tuple. The one for `score` indicates that `score` is to be mapped to itself with a transformation. It appears to be necessary to use a `lambda`; however, lambdas can't include `if` statements. For that reason I created the function `f` for the lambda to call. I think the columns are re-ordered because the container is an `OrderedDict` and it's ordered lexicographically on the names of the columns. Perhaps it doesn't have to be an `OrderedDict` but this is what I found in the doc.

Comment: Thanks for your answe! I'm glad I got to share petl with you!  I'm on the hunt for good data wrangling tools.  Considering to try out Blaze as well.  If you have any other suggestions I'd love to hear.